# LaTeX to HTML: PolyTeXnic and PlasTeX

Tags: tex4ht, html, python, latex2html

I was stunned by the elegant appearance of the [Tau manifesto page](http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto), for which the source is in LaTeX. The author used a home-made tool that he calls PolyTeXnic, but which he is not willing to release.

How difficult would it be to reproduce his result? I'm leaning towards using PlasTeX as the base tool.

**Edit** I was *not* referring to the contents of the Tau manifesto page :-) but rather to its general *appearance*: nice cross references, equations, figures, tables, cross-references to them, footnotes, bibliographical references, etc.
The maths is actually what worries me the least, thanks to MathJax. I was rather thinking on all the other aspects of the document, and whether PlasTeX might be up to the task.

Comment: It's all in the CSS.  I would add a screenshot but it'd be simpler just to show you.  The easy part of LaTeX-to-WebPage is converting LaTeX to (X)HTML.  The hard part is making it look nice - not because of anything inherent in LaTeX but just because that's the hard part of *any* webpage.

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure about the tools you're asking about, but the content of that page sure is cranky!

Comment: The fact that the idea originates with Bob Palais prevents me from completely agreeing with Mark, but while I can see the argument for pi not being *the* angle, clearly τ = π/2 and so it is the quarter circle that is the *one true* angle.

Comment: I don't think we should discuss `\pi`-or-`\tau` here or we will get into serious war, that is, moreover, more suited for Math.SX. For this reason, I won't include my opinion on the topic. As for the question: it's a matter of very fine tuning as @AndrewStacey has already mentioned. You may contact the author of the webpage and ask him for some advice.

Comment: Closest I can find is http://math.stackexchange.com/q/26918/2907 (I was hoping to find the question asked but closed as "subjective and argumentative").

Comment: Based on the source the author of the article has used `mathjax` (http://dist.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/docs/html/tex.html). Furthermore in linux you have a tool called `latex2html`. This tool can create also webpages pages. The only thing you have to do is define a nice css file.

Comment: Regarding your edit, take a look at our TeX-SX blog and in particular this article: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/getting-latex-on-to-the-web/#more-98 everything that I've written on the blog has been written in LaTeX and converted.  I also write nLab pages in LaTeX and convert them.  If that sounds interesting, drop by and I'll show you how it's done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me answer myself to myself: one of the most *reliable* ways to convert LaTeX into html is definitely [TeX4ht](http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/), because it uses TeX as the underlying engine.

TeX4ht takes care of the cross references, the figures, footnotes, bibliography, and more. The math parts are transformed into MathML which is then beautifully [rendered using MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/mathml.html).

Comment: Certainly not the *only*.  Perhaps the most complete (as in can cope with the most variation in input).

Comment: I meant the only *reliable* way (in fact, following your many comments on that topic!). Is there another package capable of coping with arbitrary custom command definitions, for instance?

Comment: Sort of.  Some external (ie using another language) methods work by allowing you to define custom extensions that will handle those custom command definitions.  My TeX class works by using tex as the interpreter so it can handle custom stuff so long as it resolves to something sensible in the output.

Comment: @AndrewStacey what is this "TeX class" you are mentioning? I'd be very glad to stay away from TeX4ht, so if you know of another reliable method, I'd like to test it.

Comment: The problem is that it isn't very reliable yet!  I've been using it, but as I wrote it then I know how to work with it and its foibles.  A description and a slightly old version is at http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/HowDidIDoThat/LaTeX/internet.html  Sometime very soon I'll put up an alpha release but there are one or two important implementation issues that I want to fix first.

Answer (score 5):

In the meantime the author of the Tau manifesto page has published his homemade PolyTeX tool. Have a look at

- https://github.com/softcover/softcover
- https://github.com/softcover/polytexnic

These tools should help you to reproduce his results.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the type and length of document/html you want to produce. The  http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto shows that all the maths are rendered via MathJax, which is easily incorporated in the html code. The way I see it you have two choices one:

1. If what you are aiming is as simple as the tau pages I would have
   done it manually via a CMS that I am comfortable with.
2. If there are many pages the [PlasTeX](http://plastex.sourceforge.net/) idea is very good and it
   wouldn't be too difficult to adapt the style and or code to what you have in
   mind.

Give it a try on a page or two first.

Comment: Obligatory warning on non-TeX converters (from the PlasTeX site): "While plasTeX makes a valiant effort to expand all LaTeX macros, it isn’t TeX and may have problems if your macros are complicated."

Comment: @AndrewStacey My honest opinion is not to use any processing here, the work will be in the CSS and and the CMS. Personally I would have done it using a Wordpress or Drupal CMS and hardcoded the code (possibly 2-3 evenings works) versus hacking code and TeX endlessly.

Comment: I agree (see my comment on the original question).  I added that comment in case anyone thought that PlasTeX (or any other TeX-to-HTML converter) were a "magic bullet" that could convert any document into a webpage.

Comment: Yiannis, would you consider the tau page as simple? There are footnotes, internal references, external references, figures, refs to figures.. is that so easy with a CMS? I should think that it would entail a significant wading through spaghetti code... Anyway, I'll give PlasTeX+tau page css a shot.

Comment: @Olivier It all depends on what you want to do. In general if you are not going to have static content then a CMS is a must. The footnotes and references is not a very difficult problem for HTML + javascript, a lot of CMSs have plugins. I must sayI like the tau page style.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried them all, and I like plastex the best. Probably the most complicated things I do with them are my annual reports, which are here:
http://fedibblety.com/annualReports

there are links to the source code if you are interested (I generate pdf and html from the same source)

Comment: Another vote for plastex, although it's a little hard to work with.  I use it to generate wordpress posts for this site: http://greedyalgs.info/ .  A few more details about that are here: http://greedyalgs.info/blog/plog/.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [DocOnce](https://hplgit.github.io/doconce/doc/web/index.html) to create a similar elegant HTML page :

> DocOnce is a modestly tagged (Markdown-like) markup language targeting scientific reports, software documentation, books, blog posts, and slides involving much math and code in the text. From DocOnce source you can generate LaTeX, Sphinx, HTML, IPython notebooks, Markdown, MediaWiki, and other formats. This means that you from a single source can get the most up-to-date publishing technologies for paper, tablets, and phones.

Some example HTML pages generated are e.g.:

- https://hplgit.github.io/teamods/writing_reports/_static/report_rossant.html
- https://hplgit.github.io/teamods/writing_reports/_static/report_github_minimal.html

For more examples, see https://hplgit.github.io/teamods/writing_reports/index.html .